# How to pass ArrayList/lists/iterables argument to a JSF1.2 custom components

Tags: java, jsf, custom-component

I am trying to show a list of images from my backing bean
which has a function

```
public getImgList(){
    return ArrayList<string>imgPathList;
}
```

Now this List has to be rendered to a equivalent output of
images which are displayed side by side.
like

```
[image][image][image]
```

Which is not possible if I use `<h:datatable>`, because it will render all of them one per row,
And I cant find any method by which I can render them 
using custom component as I will have to pass the **list** of images to the 
custom components.
Can anyone please explain how to pass a list to a custom component in JSF 1.2 Mojarra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify it as attribute.

```
<my:component value="#{bean.imagePaths}" />
```

It'll just be available as exactly the same type in the `value` property of your custom component class with help of [`UIComponent#getValueExpression()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression%28java.lang.String%29).

---

Given the fact that you're already asking this trivial question, I think developing the custom component is going to take a lot of time for you. Also, since a lot of solutions already exist, you're basically reinventing the wheel here. I'd suggest to take a different route, namely just using existing tags/components. There are two options:

- Use JSTL `<c:forEach>`. This will work if you don't put it inside another iterating component like `<h:dataTable>` and you aren't rendering input elements in the loop.

  ```
  <c:forEach items="#{bean.imagePaths}" var="imagePath">
      <img src="#{imagePath}" />
  </c:forEach>
  ```
- Use a 3rd party component library which offers a fullworthy JSF iterating component which doesn't render any HTML. I'd suggest [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/index.html) `<t:dataList>`.

  ```
  <t:dataList value="#{bean.imagePaths}" var="imagePath">
      <img src="#{imagePath}" />
  </t:dataList>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will have to write a custom component as The images are inside a <h:datattable> already hence cant use JSTL and I cant use a third party library (enterprise guidelines) Hence i will have to go the custom component way. BTW, as i am extending the component from `UIComponentBase` instead of `UIComponent` we will have to use [UIComponentBase#getAttributes](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes())